# Why are .html file parsed rather than compiled when open them in browser such as Safari?

Tags: html-parsing

Why are .html file parsed rather than compiled when open them in browser such as Safari? From the internet, I learned that parser is a component of a compiler. People say .html is parsed to a web page, but why not compiled to a web page? .html file contains code that needed to be compiled so that it becomes a webpage, right?

Some possible reasons: Maybe when we say something is compiled, it has to be compiled into machine language but .html does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML does not get compiled - it simply describes how the website should be rendered.

And that is then interpreted by the browser - it doesn't end up as machine code.

It's like a map or blue prints telling the browser's rendering engine how to build the website.

The W3C defines how these "plans" should be written and the browser vendor should make sure they interpret the plans in the correct way.

Developers should make sure they use the HTML elements properly so that the HTML files make sense and the browser can construct the web page properly.

Answer (score 0):

What difference does it make? You have not described a problem you are having.

The parsing of HTML is application-dependent. Each browser/parser decides how to do it.

HTML however must be dynamically modifiable. Since HTML is  not executed, it is not clear what the difference is between compiling and interpreting but typically compiled code can't be easily modified.

JavaScript is by definition interpreted.